# Project Problems when opening Project on NetBeans IDE 8.0.1

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a project, which when opened on NetBeans 8.0.1 always displays a pop up dialog stating "Project Problems". Upon clicking "Resolve Problems" it shows me the following errors:

[image: Screenshot of the errors]

Yes, I have images in my project, they are located in the "Libraries" folder. I can resolve the issues by locating the .zip file and logos; however, this issue arises every time I open the project. Is there a way to solve the issue once and for all?

Comment: click resolve and browse .zip

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the zip and copy its content to the project folder.
opening compressed files in rar or zip form can cause problems for IDEs, even for vs when I click on a .sln file contained in rar it first shows but then says it couldn't locate the file, so I just extract it and open it again and the problem is solved.

Comment: When opening the project, I open the folder consisting of the logo's and src. To resolve the issue I have to create the actual .zip folder which is weird.

Comment: @Freddy "To resolve the issue" what issue do you mean ?

Comment: Apologies for explaining so poorly. Those issues depicted in the image, they arise even when the.zip file doesn't exist. To resolve the first issue (highlighted in blue in the image) I have to create a .zip file of my project folder and then locate it via the "resolve" button.

Comment: @Freddy Why not just telling netbeans to open a folder instead of .zip file ? I mean to open a folder called ACME_RESERVATION_...
I think providing the code of your project would be helpful(at least where do you open the .zip file)